# How to multiply/divide/add/subtract numbers of different types?

Tags: math, rust, arithmetic-expressions

I'm working through the second edition of the Rust handbook, and decided to try and make the classic Celsius-to-Fahrenheit converter:

```
fn c_to_f(c: f32) -> f32 {
    return ( c * ( 9/5 ) ) + 32;
}
```

Compiling this with `cargo build` will yield the compile-time error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `f32: std::ops::Mul<{integer}>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:2:12
  |
2 |     return (c * (9 / 5)) + 32;
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::ops::Mul<{integer}>` is not implemented for `f32`
  |
  = note: no implementation for `f32 * {integer}`
```

As a new Rust programmer, my interpretation is that I cannot multiply float and integer types together. I solved this by making all of my constants floating points:

```
fn c_to_f(c: f32) -> f32 {
    return ( c * ( 9.0/5.0 ) ) + 32.0;
}
```

This leaves me with reservations. Coming from C/C++/Java/Python, it was surprising to learn that you cannot simply perform arithmetic on numbers of different types. Is the right thing to simply convert them to the same type, as I did here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtraction not implemented for f32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913484/subtraction-not-implemented-for-f32)

Comment: by the way, `( c * ( 9/5 ) ) + 32` => `c * (9 / 5) + 32`.

Comment: => `c * 0 + 32` => `32`

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**TL;DR**: `as` is the most common way to convert between the primitive numeric types but using it requires thinking.

```
fn c_to_f(c: f32) -> f32 {
    (c * (9 as f32 / 5 as f32)) + 32 as f32
}
```

In this example though, it's more reasonable to just use floating point literals to start with:

```
fn c_to_f(c: f32) -> f32 {
    (c * (9. / 5.)) + 32.
}
```

---

The **real** problem is that doing mixed type arithmetic is a bit complicated.

If you are multiplying<sup>1</sup> a `T` by a `T`, you generally expect to get a result of type `T`, at least with the basic types.

When mixing types, however, there are some difficulties:

- mixing signedness,
- mixing precision.

So, for example, what is the ideal result of `i8 * u32`? The smallest type that can encompass the full set of all `i8` and `u32` values is a `i64`. Should that be the result?

As another example, what is the ideal result of `f32 * i32`? The smallest type that can encompass the full set of all `f32` and `i32` values is a `f64`. Should that be the result?

I find the idea of having a such *widening* rather confusing. It also has performance impacts (operations on `f32` can be much speedier than operations on `f64`, once vectorized).

Due to those issues, Rust for now requires you to be explicit: which type do you want the computation to be carried in? Which type makes sense for your particular situation?

And then cast appropriately, using `as`, and do think about which rounding mode to apply (`.round()`, `.ceil()`, `.floor()` or `.trunc()` when going from floating point to integral).

<sup>1</sup> *Adding, Subtracting and Dividing work in similar ways*.

Comment: Maybe explain how to cast ? "What is the solution if I want to multiply/divide/add/subtract numbers of different types in the future?".

Comment: @Stargateur: Good point, it seemed obvious to me but best spell it out, especially as casting from FP to integral requiring picking the appropriate rounding mode.

Comment: Concrete example please

Comment: So, in case I want to get an f64 from dividing to u128's for example, how can you do that without casting the u128's to f64's first (because they would overflow)?.