# How do I add a signed integer to an unsigned integer in Rust?

Tags: rust

Do I have to branch on the sign of the signed integer, like in the example below? (In the real program `y` is calculated to change the index pointing into a 64K array, and wraparound is the desired behavior)

```
fn main() {
    let mut x: u16 = 100;
    let y: i8 = -1;
    //x += y;
    if y < 0 {
        x -= i8::abs(y) as u16;
    } else {
        x += i8::abs(y) as u16;
    }
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to multiply/divide/add/subtract numbers of different types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552219/how-to-multiply-divide-add-subtract-numbers-of-different-types)

Comment: @E_net4iskindandwelcoming the linked question is more about floats vs integers, not mixed signedness

Comment: The intuition, as well as the course of action, are the same. Arithmetic between integers of mixed signedness is tricky, and could have odd results if the compiler just chose an unexpected conversion ruleset (this is the case for C and C++). Just use the `from` associated function if the conversion is lossless (e.g. `i16::from(y)`) and the `as` operator otherwise.

Comment: `x = x.wrapping_add(y as u16);`?

Comment: Or better yet, `x.wrapping_add(i16::from(y))`, to conform with the [`cast_lossless`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#cast_lossless) Clippy lint.

Comment: See also [this Reddit thread on the topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3mcwf7/adding_unsigned_and_signed_integers/), which discusses how to add an `isize` and a `usize`. The only way to get this right in all cases appears to be `(if signed < 0 { unsigned - (-signed) as usize } else { unsigned + signed as usize })`.

Comment: @E_net4iskindandwelcoming, `x.wrapping_add(i16::from(y))` results in `expected u16, found i16 [E0308]`, as it's still adding a signed and an unsigned int together

Comment: Yes, you'd need to convert `x` as well. My comments were more focused on the existence of multiple numeric conversion methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rustc 1.66+ supports some mixed integer operations. Note, this was previously unstable under the [mixed_integer_ops](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87840) feature flag.

With this you can do:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x: u16 = 100;
    let y: i8 = -1;
    //x += y;
    x = x.wrapping_add_signed(y.into()); // wraps on overflow
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

These `*_add_signed` methods on unsigned integers all accept a signed argument and return an unsigned result. There's `wrapping_`, `checked_`, `saturating_`, and `overflowing_` variants, depending on how specifically you want to handle the overflow case.

There are also analogous methods on signed integers, for additions or subtractions which accept an unsigned argument and return a signed result, named `*_add_unsigned` and `*_sub_unsigned`.

Answer (score 7):

- Signed integers are twos complement
- numeric cast sign extends an `i8 as u16`

That means you can cast `y as u16` it will turn into a twos complement value that a wrapping_add will rightfully handle if `y` was negative.

In short: do as @Veedrac said.

```
fn main() {
    let mut x: u16 = 100;
    let y: i8 = -1;
    x = x.wrapping_add(y as u16);
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend doing this, but instead using the next, higher, signed value instead (in this case `i32`) and add them.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that that Rust panics on unsigned overflow, not just on signed.

Comment: @hellow care to elaborate? First this seem much more complicated and error prone, and secondly at some point (`u128`) you just can't.

Answer (score 1):

> In the real program `y` is calculated to change the index pointing into a 64K array , and wraparound is the desired behavior)

There is no consensus of how things should be done, but here's my advice: Provide to the user two functions:

```
fn add(&mut self, index: u16) -> u16 { // return previous index why not
    // ..
}

fn sub(&mut self, index: u16) -> u16 {
    // ..
}
```

You could also add a helper function that should not be used lightly:

```
fn offset(&mut self, offset: i16) -> u16 {
    // ..
}
```

The purpose is that the user should know whenever use sub or add, the user should manage only unsigned type. That question is opinion oriented so I understand if people don't agree.

Full example:

```
use std::mem;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
struct MyIndex {
    index: u16,
}

impl MyIndex {
    fn new(index: u16) -> Self {
        Self { index }
    }

    fn add(&mut self, index: u16) -> u16 {
        let index = self.index.wrapping_add(index);
        self.replace(index)
    }

    fn sub(&mut self, index: u16) -> u16 {
        let index = self.index.wrapping_sub(index);
        self.replace(index)
    }

    fn offset(&mut self, offset: i16) -> u16 {
        if offset > 0 {
            self.add(offset as u16)
        } else {
            self.sub(offset as u16)
        }
    }

    fn replace(&mut self, index: u16) -> u16 {
        mem::replace(&mut self.index, index)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut index = MyIndex::new(42);

    let mut other_index = MyIndex::new(84);

    let (x, first) = if index > other_index {
        (index.index - other_index.index, true)
    }
    else {
        (other_index.index - index.index, false)
    };

    // ...

    if first {
        index.sub(x);
    }
    else {
        other_index.sub(x);
    }
    println!("{:?} {:?}", index, other_index);

    index.sub(21);
    println!("{:?}", index);

    index.offset(-1);
    println!("{:?}", index);
}
```