# How do I add a signed integer to an unsigned integer in Rust, checking for unsigned overflow?

Tags: rust, unsigned, signed

I want to add an `isize` to a `usize` and include bounds checking so that the result does not overflow the bounds of a `usize`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rustc 1.66+ supports some mixed integer operations. Note, this was previously unstable under the [mixed_integer_ops](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87840) feature flag.

With this you can do:

```
fn main() {
    let x: usize = foo();
    let y: isize = bar();
    let (res, flag): (usize, bool) = x.overflowing_add_signed(y); // returns a (usize, bool) pair to indicate if overflow occurred
    println!("{x} + {y} = {res}, overflowed? {flag}");
}
```

These `*_add_signed` methods on unsigned integers all accept a signed argument and return an unsigned result. There's a few variants, depending on how specifically you want to handle the overflow case:

- `overflowing_`, shown above, returns a pair, with the wrapped result and a boolean flag indicating if overflow occurred.
- `checked_` returns an `Option`, which is `None` on overflow.
- `saturating_` prevents overflow by clamping to the max and min values (i.e. `MAX + 1 == MAX`, `MIN - 1 == MIN`).
- `wrapping_` doesn't address your use case - it only returns the wrapped result and doesn't indicate if overflow occurred.

There are also analogous methods on signed integers, for additions or subtractions which accept an unsigned argument and return a signed result, named `*_add_unsigned` and `*_sub_unsigned`.

(note: adapted from my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73153135/6112457)

Answer (score 5):

You could use a combination of [`isize::is_negative()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.isize.html#method.is_negative), [`isize::wrapping_abs()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.isize.html#method.wrapping_abs), [`usize::checked_add()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.checked_add) and [`usize::checked_sub()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.checked_sub).

```rust
const fn add(lhs: usize, rhs: isize) -> Option<usize> {
    if rhs.is_negative() {
        lhs.checked_sub(rhs.wrapping_abs() as usize)
    } else {
        lhs.checked_add(rhs as usize)
    }
}
```

---

Why [`isize::is_negative()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.isize.html#method.is_negative) vs `rhs < 0`? In this case, it doesn't change anything, as logical operations on literals count as [constant expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/const_eval.html#constant-expressions).

However, while it is allowed for literals it is not allowed in general, as traits methods cannot be `const`. So if you had a wrapping type, e.g. `Foo(isize)` then it wouldn't be allowed to say `foo < Foo(0)` in a const context. Though, it would be possible to say `foo.is_negative()` as `Foo` could still implement a `const fn is_negative()`.

*Yes, you'd still be able to say `foo.0 < 0`, but that's besides the point I was trying to make.*

Comment: jc, is there a reason to prefer `is_negative()` over `< 0` ?

Comment: Wouldn't this overflow if `rhs` is `isize::MIN`?

Comment: Using `x < 0` is fine as well, and yes it overflows, I've updated the answer to use `wrapping_abs()`.

Comment: @kmdreko I've added some context to why `is_negative()` vs `< 0`

Comment: @goose121 No. isize::MIN is 0b1000..000 and `-(isize::MIN+1)` is 0b0111..1111 so `isize::MIN as usize == (isize::MIN+1) as usize + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be with a function like the following:

```rust
fn signed_unsigned_add(x: usize, y: isize) -> usize {
    let (n, overflow) = x.overflowing_add(y as usize);
    if (y >= 0) ^ overflow {
        n
    } else {
        panic!(
            "signed + unsigned addition overflow: {} + {}",
            x,
            y,
        )
    }
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that such an addition, when looked at in terms of unsigned numbers, should only "overflow" (i.e. exhibit two's-complement behaviour) when the unsigned number is negative, and if it doesn't do so when the number is negative, this indicates underflow.